# multivariate competing risks failure-time data set

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I'm looking for a failure-time (survival analysis) data set 
which is
- Multivariate or clustered 
(Multiple individuals are observed in one sampling unit. For example, family members in a family)
- Competing risks
(There are multiple failure causes, for example, death from breast cancer and breast from lung cancer)

Is there such a data set?